# Mysql group_concat alternative for grails criteria projections

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria, group-concat

Let's say I have two simple domain classes:

```
class A {
    String name

    static hasMany = [bs: B]
}

class B {
    String title
}
```

Now, I want to produce a list of items structured like this:

```
// id of A instance, name of A instance, comma separated list of Bs titles associated to A istance
1, "A1", "B1, B2"
2, "A2", "B2, B5"
...
```

This is my criteria to get that:

```
def list = A.withCriteria {
    createAlias 'bs', 'bs', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN

    projections {
        property 'id'
        property 'name'

        property 'bs.title' // this is the interesting line
    }
}
```

and this obviously retrieves only the first title of the B elements related to my A instance. Like this:

```
1, "A1", "B1"
2, "A2", "B2"
...
```

Now, the real life scenario is a bit more complicated, I've simplified to get to the point, which is: how can I get the same effect of mysql group_concat for bs titles?

I'm trying to do this in a single criteria, but if it's not possible I'm happy to discuss a different solution.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I looking for a way to not use the mysql group_concat function.

Comment: I am able to get all the associations, using in-memory db, as a list. Some additional collection utility will get me what you want. `[[1, TestA1, TitleB1],[1, TestA1, TitleB2],[1, TestA1, TitleB3],[2, TestA2, TitleB2],[2, TestA2, TitleB4],[2, TestA2, TitleB5]]`. Is this behaviour particular to MySql? Can you test the same in H2 in-memory db?

Comment: @dmahapatro how do you retrieve those information? With a separate query? And how do you merge the two results? Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same implementation as yours with an ordering.

```
    def list = A.withCriteria {
        createAlias 'bs', 'bs', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN
        projections {
            property 'id'
            property 'name'
            property 'bs.title' // this is the interesting line
        }

        order "id", "asc"
        order "bs.title", "asc"
    }


    //Bootstrap
    def a = new A(name: "TestA1").save()
    def a1 = new A(name: "TestA2").save()

    def b1 = new B(title: "TitleB1")
    def b2 = new B(title: "TitleB2")
    def b3 = new B(title: "TitleB3")

    def b4 = new B(title: "TitleB4")
    def b5 = new B(title: "TitleB5")

    [b1, b2, b3].each{a.addToBs(it)}
    [b2, b4, b5].each{a1.addToBs(it)}

    [a, a1]*.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

You can groupBy to get a key value pair for each combination.

```
//This can be optimized
list.groupBy({[it[0], it[1]]})

//Would give
[[1, TestA1]:[[1, TestA1, TitleB1], [1, TestA1, TitleB2], [1, TestA1, TitleB3]], 
 [2, TestA2]:[[2, TestA2, TitleB2], [2, TestA2, TitleB4], [2, TestA2, TitleB5]]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the output isn't in the format I need it. Furthermore, these are not the only information I need from A, as I said the criteria is way more complicated and my example is very simple, and your solution is creating a data structure far more complicated that needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way

```
class A {
    String name
    static hasMany = [bs: B]

    def childrenString() {
        B.findAllByParent(this).collect{ it.title }.join(',')
    }
}

class B {
    static belongsTo = A
    A parent
    String title
    static constraints = {
    }
}

A.list().each  { it ->
    println "${it.name}, ${it.childrenString()}"
}
```

Comment: This is a possible solution but I don't really like the idea of keeping some representation logic inside the domain class.

Comment: you can place it in a service and invoke it